# R Replace Intermittent NA Values With Last Observation Carried Forward (NA.LOCF)

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

**Background**

I neeed to replace the NA's in my data frame by using different methods depending on the NA's nature. My data frame come from a study with repeated measures, where some of the Na's are a result of subjects dropping out while others are a result of intermittent missing measurements, defined as one or a sequence of multiple missing measurements, followed by a measured value.
I will be referring to intermittent missing measurements as intermittent NA's.

**Problem**

I am having trouble testing whether the NA's are the result of intermittent missing measurements, and what functions I should use to replace these NA's with. I would ideally replace these intermittent NA's with the na.locf method. But I need Dropout NA's to be replaced with the baseline OR the last value observed, whichever is greater.

**Examples**

***Example 1***

Here is a clean example of NA's that I want to be treated as intermittent NA's with the na.locf imputation:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(34,NA,NA,15,16,19,NA,12,23,31))
```

and how I want it the end result to be:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(34,34,34,15,16,19,19,12,23,31))
```

***Example 2***

Here is a clean example of NA's (dropout NA's) that I want to be imputed by the previous non-NA observation OR the baseline value (visit 1), whichever is greatest:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(34,22,18,15,16,19,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

And how I want the end result to be:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(34,22,18,15,16,19,34,34,34,34))
```

***Example 3***

Here is a complex example of a mixture of NA's which need different imputations, here where the previous non-NA observation is greater than the baseline observation (visit 1) for the dropout NA's:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(34,NA,NA,42,16,19,NA,38,NA,NA))
```

How I need the result to be:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(34,34,34,42,16,19,19,38,38,38))
```

***Example 4***

Another complex example where the baseline observation (visit 1) is greater than the previous non-NA value for the dropout NA's:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(40,NA,NA,42,16,19,NA,38,NA,NA))
```

How I need the result to be:

```
data.frame(visit=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),value=c(40,40,40,42,16,19,19,38,40,40))
```

---

**What I have tried**

As suggested by @Gregor, upon me stating that this would solve my problems, it was possible to test for the presence of intermittent NA's with:

```
mutate(is.na(value) & !is.na(lead(value))
```

But this does not help me with imputing all intermittent NA's and in particular, intermittent NA's that are in a sequence (NA1,NA2,NA3,14), where only NA3 is returned as TRUE after running this test.

Comment: You don't really give definitions, but it seems like you define an *"intermittent NA"* as an `NA` with non-missing values before and after it. Is this correct? Or do you have another definition? Or maybe you don't care how many `NA` values there are as long as there is non-NA after them? And, from your example, it seems like if there is only a single `NA` at the end, then that is considered intermittent too?

Comment: This would be a much better question if you showed some instances of `NA`s you *don't* want to fill, in addition to the example you already show where `na.locf` works as expected.

Comment: As far as *"If there was a way to test whether there was an NA followed by a non-NA measurement, that would solve my problem"*, this works: `mutate(is.na(value) & !is.na(lead(value)))`. But it will return `FALSE` for that last value because it is `NA` and not followed by a non-NA value.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of properly defining what I meant @Gregor. In this case, what I mean by Intermittent NAs , is one or a sequence of NAs, that are eventually followed by a non-NA value. Essentially, whenever there is a non-NA value at the end of the "NA tunnel", they should be treated as intermittent NA's. In the event of the last value being an NA and the the second last value being a non-NA, that would be considered as an NA as the result of dropout and not treated as an intermittent NA, regardless of how the previous NA's were treated. I will try your suggestion straight away.

Comment: @Nowak As Gregor said, it would really help if you could provide sample data that includes both `NA`s that you *do* and *do not* want to replace. Your problem statement is still somewhat obscure to me, perhaps due to unconventional terminology *"Essentially, whenever there is a non-NA value at the end of the "NA tunnel", they should be treated as intermittent NA's."*

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I have edited my post and added more examples for clarification.

Comment: @Nowak Thanks, that helps. A follow-up question: In the second example, you say that you want `NA`s *"to be imputed by the previous non-NA observation or the baseline value, whichever is greatest:"* What is the "baseline value"? In your example it simply seems to be the first value. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Nowak Also: The third example does not seem more complex to me. You can achieve the expected output with a simple locf-approach (as in the first example).

Comment: @MauritsEvers yes, the first observation for each example is the baseline value.
I have edited the post to clarify this.
Also, I have added an example 4, that is more complex than example 3. I need the code to choose the greatest value for dropout NA's (have been clarified in my edited post), previous non-NA or the baseline value. Example 3 needs to choose the previous non-NA while example 4 needs to choose the baseline value for the dropout NA's.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.locf(..., fromLast = TRUE)` to identify the trailing `NA` values and use `pmax` on them with the baseline. We'll demonstrate on the examples from your question in a nice all-together format:

```
# consolidate example data
dd = data.frame(
  example = rep(1:3, each = 10),
  visit = rep(1:10, 3),
  value = c(34,NA,NA,15,16,19,NA,12,23,31,
            34,22,18,15,16,19,NA,NA,NA,NA,
            34,NA,NA,42,16,19,NA,38,NA,NA),
  goal = c(34,34,34,15,16,19,19,12,23,31,
           34,22,18,15,16,19,34,34,34,34,
           34,34,34,42,16,19,19,38,38,38)
)

library(dplyr)
dd = dd %>% group_by(example) %>%
  mutate(to_fill = !is.na(zoo::na.locf(value, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)),
         result = if_else(to_fill,
                          zoo::na.locf(value, na.rm = FALSE),
                          pmax(first(value), zoo::na.locf(value, na.rm = FALSE))),
    )

all(dd$goal == dd$result)
# [1] TRUE
```

As you can see, the `result` matches the `goal` column perfectly.

Comment: Hi @Gregor. Great thinking with fromLast = TRUE! 
This does what I wanted to do.
Do you know how to impute the dropout NA's by adding +2 after each 3 visit interval starting from the last available non-NA value? So if the first dropout NA happens in visit 2 and the observation for visit 1 was 34, then :
(visit = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
value = c(34,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
needs to be
(visit = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
value = c(34,34,34,36,36,36,38,38,38,40))

Comment: If you've got a new question, ask a new question. Something with `rep` and `seq` should work.

Comment: I'll add a new question.

Comment: Here is my new question if you have the answer for it :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506312/r-impute-nas-by-linear-increase-depending-on-time-interval