# R Impute NA's by Linear Increase Depending on Time Interval

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

***PROBLEM***

I neeed to impute the NA's in my data frame that comes from a repeated measures study. On this particular outcome, I need to impute the NA's with the last observed non-NA value *+1* by each *+52* week interval starting from the last observed value.

***EXAMPLE***

An example data frame with the target imputation goal included.

```
df <- data.frame(
  subject = rep(1:3, each = 12),
  week = rep(c(8, 10, 12, 16, 20, 26, 32, 44, 52, 64, 78, 104),3),
  value = c(112, 97, 130, 104, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
            89, 86, 94, 96, 88,107, 110, 102, 107, NA, NA, NA,
            107, 110, 102, 130, 104, 88, 82, 79, 92, 106, NA, NA),
  goal = c(112, 97, 130, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105,
            89, 86, 94, 96, 88,107, 110, 102, 107, 107,107, 108,
            107, 110, 102, 130, 104, 88, 82, 79, 92, 106, 106, 106)
)
```

Comment: Whats logic to have `goal` as 105 for row number 11&12?

Comment: Because in rows 11 and 12, the `week` value is more than 52 weeks from that last observed value.

Comment: Since row 4 is the last observed non-NA value for subject 1 = 104, which was measured in week 16, the +1 imputation needs to take place from week 16+52=68 and onwards. row 11&12 is week 78&104, meaning that these NA's need to be imputed by 104+1=105.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I left the intermediate columns in to make what's happening more obvious, but you can remove them with a simple `select`.

```
df = df %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(last_obs_week = max(week[!is.na(value)]),
         since_last_week = pmax(0, week - last_obs_week),
         inc_52 = since_last_week %/% 52,
         result = zoo::na.locf(value) + inc_52
  ) 

all(df$goal == df$result)
# [1] TRUE

print.data.frame(df)
#    subject week value goal last_obs_week since_last_week inc_52 result
# 1        1    8   112  112            16               0      0    112
# 2        1   10    97   97            16               0      0     97
# 3        1   12   130  130            16               0      0    130
# 4        1   16   104  104            16               0      0    104
# 5        1   20    NA  104            16               4      0    104
# 6        1   26    NA  104            16              10      0    104
# 7        1   32    NA  104            16              16      0    104
# 8        1   44    NA  104            16              28      0    104
# 9        1   52    NA  104            16              36      0    104
# 10       1   64    NA  104            16              48      0    104
# 11       1   78    NA  105            16              62      1    105
# 12       1  104    NA  105            16              88      1    105
# 13       2    8    89   89            52               0      0     89
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

One can use `dplyr` and `tidyr::fill` to get the desired result. The logic will be to add a column to track the `week` which had the `non-NA` value. Use `tidyr::fill` to populate last `non-NA` value and then check if difference of current week with last `non-NA` week is more than `52` then increase the value by `1`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(weekWithLastNonNaValue = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, week)) %>%
  fill(value, weekWithLastNonNaValue) %>%
  mutate(value = value + (week-weekWithLastNonNaValue) %/% 52) %>%
  select(-weekWithLastNonNaValue) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# subject week value goal
# 1        1    8   112  112
# 2        1   10    97   97
# 3        1   12   130  130
# 4        1   16   104  104
# 5        1   20   104  104
# 6        1   26   104  104
# 7        1   32   104  104
# 8        1   44   104  104
# 9        1   52   104  104
# 10       1   64   104  104
# 11       1   78   105  105
# 12       1  104   105  105
# 13       2    8    89   89
# 14       2   10    86   86
# 15       2   12    94   94
# 16       2   16    96   96
# 17       2   20    88   88
# 18       2   26   107  107
# 19       2   32   110  110
# 20       2   44   102  102
#
# so on
#
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `%/%` for the incremental value as in my answer so it generalizes to cases with larger offsets - OP says it needs to be +1 for each +52 week difference, which I think means +2 for 104, +3 for 156, etc. (Partially based on OP's comments [on this other question that led to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51489800/903061))

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. Yes, if OP intention was to increment +1 for each 52 then `%/%` is needed. I'll update my answer.